# Using global variables in Python modules

Tags: python, global-variables

I have these 4 modules
globals.py

```
globvara = "a"
```

mod1.py

```
from globals import *

print globvara
```

output : a

mod2.py

```
from mod1 import *

def changegv(newval1):
    #global globvara
    globvara = newval1

def usechangegv(newval2):
    changegv(newval2)
```

and mod3.py

```
from mod2 import *

usechangegv("b")

print globvara
```

output : 
a
a

I am wondering why the globalvar does not change in module 2. I am missing something in global variables. Even if I uncomment the global globvara line I get the same result. Where is the error?

Comment: Out of interest, are you doing this as an experiment to get familiar with how scoping works in Python or do you actually have such case in a program you're writing?

Comment: I am working on a bigger project and I simplified it.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630386/how-to-use-a-dictionary-loaded-from-one-module-into-the-main-program-from-anothe (but not a diff, I think, both because this question wants to be able to _assign_ to `globvara` in each module, not just access it, and because he's not asking how to "work around" this problem, just asking what's happening).

Comment: As far as the assignment goes: Presumably you know that `globvara = newval1` will create a new local even if there's a global of the same name, unless you uncomment that `global` statement. But even with that statement, it will create a new (module-)global  even if there's a builtin of the same name, and there is no `builtin` statement to override that.

Answer (score 5):

Python global variables are global only to modules. When you import a variable from another module (e.g. `from mod1 import *`), Python creates *duplicate* references to the value in the importing module. So you now have two names, `mod1.globvara` and `mod2.globvara`, which initially point to the same value, but which are not in any way connected. If you change `globvara` in `mod2.py`, you are changing `mod2.globvara` and `mod1.globvara` *is not affected.*

To avoid this problem, import the module, not the individual names defined in it.  For example, `import globals`.  Then always refer to `globals.globvara` (or better yet, `globals.a`). Since you are always accessing and assigning the same name, it will work the way you expect.

Comment: As I have explained, you can't; not the way you want.

Comment: @Yannis: Actually, you _can_, by storing it in builtins instead of in a module. But you really, really don't want to. (See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630386/how-to-use-a-dictionary-loaded-from-one-module-into-the-main-program-from-anothe/25630506#25630506) for why not—and also, coincidentally, for how.)

Comment: Also be aware of the built-in function globals - better to use another name for your module.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the

```
from <module> import <variable>
```

As it creates a copy of the variable.

Do a simple:

```
import <module>
```

And all accesses to the global variable should use the "variable" within "module":

```
<module>.<variable> = ...
```

or

```
print <module>.<variable>
```